# SQL - extracting data from 3 tables

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and I'm wondering how to extract the relevant data from the sites and plugins table using the sites_plugins table. The data I am interested in is sites.description, plugins.fullName, plugins.currentVersion and sites_plugins.syncedAt

Below are the sql tables

```
INSERT INTO sites (id, name, description) VALUES
  (1, "facebook", "Facebook"),
  (2, "amazon", "Amazon"),
  (3, "google", "Google");

INSERT INTO plugins (id, name, fullName, currentVersion) VALUES
  (1, "yoast", "Yoast SEO", "16.8"),
  (2, "jetpack", "Jetpack", "9.9.1"),
  (3, "akismet", "Akismet", "4.1.10"),
  (4, "wordfence", "Wordfence Security", "7.5.4"),
  (5, "contact-form", "Contact Form 7", "7.5.4.2");

INSERT INTO sites_plugins (siteId, pluginId, version, syncedAt) VALUES
  (1, 1, "16.8", NULL),
  (1, 3, "3.8", '2021-07-01 10:00:00'),
  (2, 3, "4.1.10", NULL),
  (2, 5, "7.0", NULL),
  (2, 4, "7.5.3", '2021-06-15 12:00:00');
```

Ultimately, I would very much like to achieve a data format like the following

```
{["Amazon", "Jetpack", "16.8", "NULL"]}
```

Thanks for any advice, Best Kacper

Comment: You need a `join`

Comment: Personally I think it is really good to play around with SQL on the command line. I installed SQLite and I use this tutorial: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/. Also see https://www.sqlite.org/index.html. An SQLite database is a single file and unlike most things like MySQL it is not based on a server / client model which ultimately limits how much traffic it can handle but those limits are very high. It makes it simpler to configure and manage.

Answer (score 0):

You must join all tables by thier linking column and pick for the SELECT the wanted columns, which you can freely pick from all tables

```
SELECT
    s.description
    ,p.fullName
    ,sp.version
    , sp.syncedAt
FROM sites_plugins  sp 
INNER JOIN sites  s ON s.id = sp.siteId
INNER JOIN plugins  p = p.id = sp.pluginId
```

But your wanted result is not possible with the data you provided